Is implementing a daily limit for consecutive sampling considered a type of quota sampling?

The present study used a consecutive sampling method to obtain the
required number of patients. Using this technique, we consecutively
invited every 5th T2DM patient from the outpatient diabetes care
facilities to participate in the study until we obtained the minimum
required sample (n = 677). A total of 805 participants were invited
for the present study. Every 5th patient recruitment strategy was
selected after a focus group discussion with the physicians at the
diabetes care facilities to avoid the possibility of patients from the
same family sharing the same sociodemographic background
characteristics. Furthermore, we restricted the maximum per day to 10
patients from each type of facility to enroll patients over a longer
period of time.
Evaluation of oral health-related quality of life and its association with mental health status of patients with type 2 diabetes mellitus in the post-COVID-19 pandemic era: A study from Central Saudi Arabia

If yes, I would like references from literature or self-experience.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
